# Civimail token not recognized

Tags: civimail, tokens

I have a question, I am running Drupal 7.54 and CiviCRM 4.7.18. I have created an html template with 3 tokens (from Mailings->New Mailing) {contact.first_name} and the two required which are {domain.address}{action.optOutUrl}

My problem is that in html preview of the email, The contact.firstname points to the name of the sender instead to the 1 participant of the group in the mass-mailing option. I wonder why this is happening. Any clues?

The other 2 tokens are filled correcly in html preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. The preview replaces tokens based on the the logged-in viewer. If you send the email, the tokens will be replaced appropriately for each recipient.

Comment: Sending the emails to different mail providers it seems that the attribute cannot be read from gmail/outlook but it can be read from yahoo. Is there any way to check if the name is coming with the email? Maybe checking the source code of the email can give me more information?
If it helps yahoo mail comes as plain text which is weird since I have tested the template on a service which checks with different providers.

Comment: You should be able to see you HTML email in Yahoo. 
I don't know what you mean by "the attribute". 

The various email clients/services each support a different subset of HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276995/html-email-looks-different-in-yahoo-hotmail-and-gmail

Comment: I know various email clients support different subset of html, that is why i tested my html template on such a service which tests different providers and clients. By attribute I was talking about {contact.first_name} it gets displayed correctly in yahoo but not in gmail/outlook under the same template.

Comment: In CiviCRM terminology, {contact.first_name} is called a token. Are you saying that you're sending it to Contact-A in Yahoo (and seeing Contact-A's first name) and to Contact-B in gmail/outlook (and not seeing Contact-B's first name)? What exactly are you seeing in gmail/outlook that makes you say it does not get displayed correctly, and what do you expect to see?

Comment: I re-tested and everything seems fine, i was making a mistake with profiles that is why token was not recognized